# What would be a good fault tolerant sceme for a small Windows Server-Exhange domain?

Tags: windows, exchange-2013

We are out to setup a Windows 2012r2 server with Exchange 2013.
It is just to be a simple single domain at one site with about 25 users.
So my boss want something that is fault tolerant, if the hardware or software fails we can come up within a day.
My boss is talking of buying two Server boxes just to have hardware redundancy in the coming years,  but I am unsure because I do not think we also want to buy addition server licenses?  Would we need to buy 2 copies of the software?
So the question is what kind of simple server setup do you advise for this?

Comment: I would be nice to show where this question has been asked and answered before rather than just saying it has been asked and shutting me down.

Comment: My question is not about licensing at all!  My question is about how one can maintain a Windows Server 2012r2 system in such a way it is fault tolerant.  I suggest my boss is saying buy two and I am asking for better solutions.